# Getting quote (cart) items programatically shows duplicate SKUs for both the configurable and simple product

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, addtocart

I'm getting the shopping cart using:

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
```

And then iterating through it using:

```
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) { }
```

But it seems to be returning duplicate items with the same SKUs, but different product ids! On the main site, when I open the cart, however, it shows the single product.

```
cart: {
    id: 680,
    items: [
        {
            name: "Tori Tank",
            price: "60.0000",
            id: "418",
            sku: "wbk004"
        },
        {
            name: "Tori Tank",
            price: "60.0000",
            id: "286",
            sku: "wbk004"
        }
    ]
}
```

My question is.. Why is this happening? Shouldn't the parent (configurable) product be showing its own unique Sku?

Also, if I want to add a product to the cart, should I add the configurable product? Or do I add the simple product and Magento handles the rest?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to Magento, when a configurable product added at cart then two rows are inserted at the database. one configurable product cart another is a simple product

- `One row has configurable id and simple product SKU and parent item id is null`
- `Other rows have simple id and simple product SKU and parent item id should above row id`

As you have using `getAllItems()` then on for loop you need to `check` is it  has `parent item $item->getParentItemId()`.

```
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
    / * add this */
    if ($item->getParentItemId()) {
        continue;
    }
........
}
```

Comment: You can also used  Marius code  for user visibility purpose

Comment: There is a problem though.. I can't get the color, size, etc.. When I use the getAllVisibleItems(). How should I do that?

Comment: yes it possible by using Product  model by Sku,because sku is same for two.. rowss

Answer (score 10):

Use `$cart->getAllVisibleItems()` instead of `$cart->getAllItems()`.
You get duplicates because when adding a configurable product to the cart, magento actually adds 2 products, the simple product and the configurable product but only one is visible for the user.

Comment: If I add a simple product, it will automatically add the configurable one as well? Or do I need to do it manually?

Comment: No. When you add a configurable product, there will be 2 in the cart,.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();

foreach ($cart->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) 
{ 
  echo $productName = $item->getProduct()->getName();
  echo $productPrice = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
  echo $grandTotal = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
  echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($item->getProduct(), 'small_image')->resize(50,50);
}

?>
```

Comment: Add code in <?php ?> for all lines